# Chrome and Safari keeps hanging after upgrading to macOS High Sierra

Tags: safari, google-chrome, performance, high-sierra, console

Since upgrading to High Sierra, both Chrome and Safari have been hanging randomly following startup. The rainbow pinwheel would appear every few seconds and I'd have to force quit/re-open those applications. However, the same problem keeps recurring no matter how many times I restart.

The only potential solution that I've come across is from https://setapp.com/how-to/fix-macos-high-sierra-problems:

> GETTING THE RAINBOW WHEEL EVERY FEW SECONDS AFTER UPGRADE
>
> Check console.app and if you’re getting errors from sandboxd and hidd
>   (IOKit), your problem is a third party software. It’s probably because
>   it wasn’t supported by the new APFS file system. It tries to
>   repeatedly update causing your Mac laptop to be stuck in an endless
>   loop. To fix this issue, just find and remove this app and everything
>   will be fine.

Following these instructions I found that there was a reoccurring error with hidd, however, I am unable to make sense of the message. Could someone kindly explain what it means?

[image]

Otherwise, has anyone had a similar issue with Chrome/Safari? Would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to know exactly which application is causing this error. I would start by making sure macOS High Sierra is up to date, then update all of your third party software. First, make sure you have installed the macOS High Sierra Supplemental Update, then check any third-party software you have installed to make sure it is all up to date. Does this issue only occur in your web browsers? Are both Chrome and Safari up to date?

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jake3231; all my apps are up to date. I realised shortly after that my audio had issues too, which led me to find this thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87240 Turns out there's a driver called InstantOn that's been causing issues with both audio and web browsing. Deleting it resolved both issues!

Comment: That's great to hear! Glad it was that simple to resolve!

Answer (score 1):

Frustrating to say the least.  try this: http://scaleup.us/2017/11/09/high-sierra-slow-chromefirefox-issues/

It appears to be an issue with the WindowServer running when running your display in scaled mode.  After setting the resolution for my displays to "Default for display" chrome and firefox issues disappeared.
Granted, the resolution is shit, waste of my 4k displays but, I'll take that over the freezing nonsense.

Comment: Sadly, this is still useful on 10.13.2